# 4-way interaction with ggplot2 lines and points defined by color and linetype

Tags: r, ggplot2, anova, interaction

I'm trying to plot a 4-way interaction from a factorial experiment using `ggplot2` with `geom_line()` and `geom_point()`.

Data I'm working with is `emmeans()` object with marginal means estimated from a linear mixed-effects model.

And the graph I can get via `emmip()` is this:

[image]

What I'd like is to separate `b:c` interaction so that one factor is defined by color and / or point type and the other by linetype (dashed vs. solid)

A minimal example is this:

```
df<- data.frame(y=rnorm(n=16),
                a=gl(2,4,16, labels=c("a1","a2")),
                b=gl(2,2,16, labels=c("b1", "b2")),
                c=gl(2,1,16, labels=c("c1", "c2")),
                fac=gl(2,8,16, labels=c("panel1", "panel2")))
```

I tried the following `ggplot()` code:

```
ggplot(df, aes(y=y, x=a, color=b)) + 
      geom_point(aes(shape=b), size=3) +
      geom_line(aes(linetype=c)) +
      facet_wrap(~fac)
```

But I get a warning that I don't know how to handle:

```
geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
```

And the graph looks *almost* as intended, but without the `c` factor horizontal lines drawn between corresponding `b` points:

[image]

**How can I fix this?**

I found a similar question dealing directly with predicted values from a `lmer()` object: [How to plot mixed-effects model estimates in ggplot2 in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45679109/6925293) but still can't find a way to deal with my data format.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your need correctly, but perhaps try adding `group = b:c` inside `geom_line(aes(...))`?

Comment: Thanks for this hint. I've been able to produce a graph exactly the way I wanted.

Comment: You can always set up the basic plot you want using emmip(), then use the data frame it returns as the data source for plotting those results with the line styles and colors that you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following [Z.Lin comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51608155/4-way-interaction-with-ggplot2-lines-and-points?noredirect=1#comment90194401_51608155) I found what I was looking for with:

```
ggplot(df, aes(y=y, x=a)) + 
      geom_point(aes(color=b),size=3) +
      geom_line(aes(group = b:c, color=b, linetype=c), size=1) +
      facet_wrap(~fac)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One problem with your example is that you use both color and shape aesthetics for the variable *b*. I would recommend to choose one and save the other for the variable *c* rather than using lines. Generally speaking, using lines makes sense for continuous variables and trends. You can use one of the following:

```
# colored by b & shaped by c
ggplot(df, aes(y=y, x=a, color=b)) + 
  geom_point(aes(shape=c), size=3) +
  facet_wrap(~fac)

# colored by c & shaped by b
ggplot(df, aes(y=y, x=a, color=c)) + 
  geom_point(aes(shape=b), size=3) +
  facet_wrap(~fac)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but that's not really what I want to get. I'm aware that lines are counter intuitive when dealing with categorical factors. Nevertheless this is how SPSS plots interactions and that's what I've been asked for. Is there anyway to make it work?
In other words, can I still connect circles with one linetype and triangles with an other linetype?

Comment: I don't think so. Your code is trying to draw lines based on the variable c and shapes are based on the variable b. So, connecting same shapes with same type of line means you are connecting factors of b not.

Comment: Maybe I did not explain myself clearly. Can you see the 1st graph in my question? I just added it. Logically I see no reason why I can't separate the `b:c` interaction to a `b` color type and `c` shape type.